# Ordered rings tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that while there are tags ordered-groups and ordered-fields, there is no tag ordered-rings. The issue is that there was a little amount of questions with this tag. So it got deleted.

I propose the following solutions:

Rename ordered-groups to ordered-groups-and-rings, or rename ordered-fields to ordered-fields-and-rings.

Comment: As [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2024/3/26), the tags (ordered-rings) and (ordered-semirings) were previously created [in August 2022](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2022/8/21). Since no other question used any of those tags for a long time and the tag-info was empty, they were eventually removed [by the tag-pruning script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info).

Answer (score 3):

Certainly renaming [ordered-groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ordered-groups) into [ordered-groups-and-rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ordered-groups-and-rings) would be counterproductive, because a large part of the research on ordered groups concerns 1-dimensional dynamics and unrelated to ring/field theory.

On the other hand, I tend to think that replacing [ordered-fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ordered-fields) with [ordered-rings-and-fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ordered-rings-and-fields) would be natural and fine. Probably it would be fine to encompass semirings too. In a sense, the main default of [ordered-fields-rings-semirings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ordered-fields-rings-semirings) would be its length but this is not a major obstruction.

Comment: I don't think such an unwieldy name is necessary. Just make it [tag:ordered-rings]. This would include ordered fields as a special case, and ordered semirings by analogy.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek yes I agree